# Heat pump not draining; barely cooling & smells bad

Tags: hvac, heat-pump

I have a Panasonic heat pump system for heating and cooling. The inverter unit is an R410A. I can't get access to the outdoor unit (I'm a tenant and it's in another part of the building). This is my second year with it; I think it's about 9 years old. It worked fine last summer and last winter. I switched it to cooling yesterday and noticed some issues:

1. It blows very cold for the first 10-15 minutes of being on, then blows gradually warmer air. I've been getting around this by turning it off for 10 minutes every half hour or so.
2. There is no water coming out of the exterior drain pipe (water came out fine last summer).
3. After about 24 hours of running, the air that comes out is starting to smell really bad, like damp mould.

It was serviced about a year and a half ago; the tech found no issues apart from the vent motors being broken. Like I said above, I'm a tenant, so I can't really do diy. Does anyone know what's wrong, and a quick fix?

Comment: You need to contact the owner/landlord and file a complaint since you can't really do any repair work on your own.

Comment: Most likley freezing the coil due to restricted air flow into the unit.  Filter could be clogged or something is sitting in front of return register?   And finally water should be draining away not standing inside the unit. Drain lines need inspected

Comment: I would agree with evaporator coil icing turning off when you notice a reduction in flow allows the coil to warm up and melt. The bad smell could be from growth in the coil and drip pan many describe this as a dirty sock smell. A low refrigerant charge or over charge can cause icing.